# Possible to do .net programming with Visual Studio Community Mac?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/

There's a screenshot from this webpage that looks like I can do .net programming with the Mac version of Visual Studio Community. However, it seemed like I could only do Android and iOS development after downloaded Visual Studio Mac.

Is there a way to do .net programming in Visual Studio Community Mac? I'd rather not have to use a VM to do .net programming.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the question? It is not very clear what you're asking for? To quote *Craft the front-end with the same web editor experience you know and love from Visual Studio and Windows and publish to the cloud directly from the IDE.* is saying it all.

Comment: @t0mm13b "Is there a way to do .net programming in Visual Studio Community Mac?" I thought it was pretty clear, honestly.

Comment: @t0mm13b OP wants to be able to develop .net applications using Visual Studio for Mac - if you installed VSMac without having the .net core SDK installed, it does indeed look as though you can just do Android / iOS dev

Comment: There is a large documentation site, so I wonder why you stopped at a single page and then post such a question without fully studying the topic, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Visual Studio for Mac to develop .net (core) applications.

You will need to have the .net core SDK installed on your mac:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos

Don't expect a like-for-like experience between Windows based Visual Studio and Visual Studio for Mac.
A lot of things are missing, not to mention, it's only compatible with .net core.

Comment: Then you simply ignore all those Mono projects, where many actually more than .NET Core.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment?